# Background image scrolling too when website is scrolling

Tags: html, css, background

I have one page that have one background, that i want to move when the website is scrolling so the website will always have one background.  But the problem is that i am having problems to apply that. I tried everything that i saw on tutorials and nothing.

html:

```
<body>

<div class="container-fluid vh-100">
</div>

</body>
```

css:

```
body{
  background: url("src/assets/Images/addPlayer/background1.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

but the website on phone view stays like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove "fixed" value from "background" css property.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to achieve.

```
body {
 background-image: url(..);
 background-size: cover;
 min-height: 100vh; => make sure the body will cover the window
 background-attachment: fixed; => the image will stay fixed in the window and the content of your page will "move over it"
 background-attachment: scroll; => the image will fill the entire body according to its content
}
```